# GUID foldername on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

Recently I'm seeing GUID folder names pop up on the system drive of my Server 2008 R2 machine (example below). Does anyone have any idea as to what might be causing these? If you open the folder there's nothing only an empty amd64 folder within.

.[image]

I think it might be WSUS unpacking patches and failing to clean up properly after itself

**EDIT 2014-11-24 Added screenshot of permissions**

[image: Permissions on folder]

Comment: What about the permissions on the folder? If it's TrustedInstaller, then the source could be from WSUS, WU, or just plain old installations. I see this often with C/C++ redistriubutable installers. Sometimes I have to take ownership of these folders in order to see the contents, as the permissions are set to not list the contents to any account besides TrustedInstaller. Are there any other files/folders in the drive that have the same or close timestamps? That information can point to what package created the folder if the folder indeed contains no files.

Comment: Perms are SYSTEM and local Admins group. There are other similarly named folders with the same perms also in the drive.

Comment: Do the timestamps on the folders match the time that WSUS is applying patches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close--close enough that the folders might have been created as part of the Windows Update process.  But Windows update itself didn't unpack the patches there--it always downloads to %windir%\SoftwareDistribution\Download.

These folders were created by Windows Installer.  To quote from [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371372%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> The ROOTDRIVE property specifies the default drive for the destination
>   directory of the installation. If the Directory column of the
>   Directory table indicates the root destination directory by a property
>   name that is undefined, the installer uses the value of the ROOTDRIVE
>   property to resolve the path to the destination directory.
>
> If ROOTDRIVE is not set at a command line or authored into the
>   Property table, the installer sets this property. During an
>   administrative installation the installer sets ROOTDRIVE to the first
>   connected network drive it finds that can be written to. If it is not
>   an administrative installation, or if the installer can find no
>   network drives, the installer sets ROOTDRIVE to the local drive that
>   can be written to having the most free space.

Comment: And since you didn't state it explicitly, they're temporary folders, and safe to delete.  (Assuming the installation is finished, at least.)  You just have to take ownership and grant yourself permissions first, which is a bit of a pain.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Yes, I've been deleting them and with no need to take ownership as members of the domain admins group is already there

Comment: Katherine, there's nothing being installed on the machine, it's a server, so I tend to leave it alone as much as possible. It's something that's just after starting in the past month and it's a little bit of PITA having to clean up after it that's all. Having authored MSI/MSP installs I'm familiar with the ROOTDRIVE property. It's an install of some kind definitely but what kind?

Comment: It's hard to say based on the information provided, but my wild guess would be Windows Update--it uses the Installer process--or perhaps your antivirus is performing engine updates?

Comment: Forefront it is, the event log has a slew of "Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x80070643: Update for Forefront Endpoint Protection 2010 Client (KB2907566)" roughly correlated with the timestamp on the folder. Fix that and I guess the issue will go away. Awarding answer to you on the basis of this. Thanks!